# ModX Revo PdoPage вывести страницу "ничего не найдено", если нет результатов

Tags: pdo, modx

Собссно, сабж.
PdoPage выводит код на страницу по определённым параметрам.
А если ничего не выводит, как показать сообщение, что нет результатов?

```
[[!pdoPage?
    &parents=`15`
    &ajaxMode=`scroll`
    &limit=`6`
    &tpl=`antr.row`
    &where=`тут условие`
    ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте модификатор вывода:

```
[[!pdoPage:default=`Результаты отсутствуют`?
    &parents=`15`
    &ajaxMode=`scroll`
    &limit=`6`
    &tpl=`antr.row`
    &where=`тут условие`
    ]]
```

подробнее о модификаторах: https://modx.ws/blog/blog-o-modx-revolution/filtry-vvoda-vyvoda.html